# Trying to iterate through a graph breadth first in Python

Tags: python, data-transfer

In my code, I am essentially trying to create an implementation of a data flow network. Although the particularities of how I am going about doing this aren't particularly important, I need some help to make the program go through the graph in a breadth first fashion.
When I do this with my code:

```
def traverse(self):
    source = self._nodelist[0]
    self.sand_pile(source)
    return

def sand_pile(self, start):
    for sink in start._sinks:
        //ALGORITHM FOR SENDING DATA HERE
    for s in start._sinks:
        self.sand_pile(s)
    return
```

The compiler correctly goes through the first node and its sinks breadth first, but then when it goes on to repeat the process for the sinks, it starts to go depth first.

Another way of explaining this is the following: if the source of the graph has two or three sinks, each of which have two or three of their own sinks, the compiler will print them all out and pass the value to them successfully, but then will proceed to go depth first for the rest of the nodes until it reaches the end. Where am I going wrong in my logic?

P.S. If I am not explaining anything well, please leave a comment so I can clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing BFS (*breadth first search*) and DFS (*depth first search*) in your approach.

When sending data in your `sand_pile` method, you iterate horizontally through all children of the current node, which probably is your approach of implementing a BFS. But as soon as the first level of children (or *sinks* in your case) is done, you perform a *recursion* step on each of the child nodes. This essentially results in a schema like this:

- Start `sand_pile` on node on level `0` (root node)
- Distribute data to all its children on level `1`
- Start `sand_pile` on first children of level `1`
- Distribute data to all of its children on level `2`
- ... keep on going DFS with out-of-line data distribution

**The flaw is, that you employ recursion for a BFS.**

You can use a recursive descent (i.e. *stack-like* iteration) for DFS, but for BFS, you should create a buffer that contains all nodes in the desired order (i.e. *queue-like* iteration)

The steps can then be like the following

1. Get maximum depth of your tree
2. For each depth level, put all nodes that reside on that level into a list
3. Concatenate all lists to obtain something like `[lvl0_node0, lvl1_node0, lvl1_node1, lvl1_node2, lvl2_node_0, ..., lvlN_nodeM]`
4. Iterate over that queue

Comment: Hey man, thank you for the answer. There is a problem with it though. When I try do this on a more complex graph, where potentially one node is on "multiple" levels, obviously I run into a problem. I'm not going to assign these hypothetical levels each time, so is there an alternative to fix this issue?

Comment: If a node may be part of multiple levels (i.e. it occurs multiple times in your node list), you may want to carry a *visited* list. Just push each node's reference in there once it is done and check against this list before performing actions for any other node.